# Execute string as a code in a function

Tags: javascript

the eval function is using a string and calculate it yeah ?
Isthere a function that takes an string like "console.log (lol)" as a parameter and execute it?

An exemple of what i need :

```
execute("for(var cpt=0;cpt<5;cpt++){alert('lol');}");
```

Its because i need to execute the code asked by the client, thanks :D

Comment: Just a warning, this is a security **nightmare** . . . allowing the user to enter in code and then executing whatever it is that they've entered will allow them to cause an innumerable amount of trouble.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)

Comment: Gentlemen, it would be a security nightmare anywhere except code on the client, that is executed in the browser that generated it. If I read this right, he's trying to use it where it would be safe.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
eval("for(var cpt=0;cpt<5;cpt++){alert('lol');}");
```

Comment: @AntoineDuval You are welcome, if I helped you, tell everyone by clicking the little check mark!